# ColorBox not picking up script from behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox

I'm using a colorbox to show some images. The code i use to call the images is:

```
jQuery(".ImgPop").colorbox({
    opacity: 0.4,
    rel: 'ImgPop',
    iframe: false,
    width: '770px',
    height: '680px',
    scalePhotos: true,
    current: false
});
```

This works fine and pops up my images where i can navigate through them.

My problem is on the original page where i call the code above i have a scrip that prevents any right clicking on images using the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("img").bind("contextmenu",function(e){
        alert('Images are Copyright of this site.');
            return false;
    });
});
```

This code works for everything on my site apart from colorbox. Is there any way to pass this script through to the colorbox or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hhahahah.. XD nice title!

Comment: See this http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/click-events/  You might find something there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do this...

This is the code I used:

```
// This is used to prevent right clicks on images within colorbox
jQuery(document).bind('cbox_complete', function(){ 
    jQuery("img").bind("mousedown",function(e){
        if(e.which == 3){
            alert('Images are Copyright of this site.');
            return false;
        }

    });
});

// This removes the above mousedown event so that outside of colorbox
// the prevent image notification does not show twice.
jQuery(document).bind('cbox_closed', function(){ 
    jQuery("img").unbind("mousedown");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
      e.preventDefault()
});
```

Or go with this:

```
$('img').on('contextmenu', function(e){
    return false;
});
```

Or

```
$(document).on('mousedown', 'img', function(e){
    if(e.which === 3){
        $(this).on('contextmenu', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Im sorry but I dont think this part is the problem. The img bind script works fine everywhere else in the site. IT just doesnt seem to be picking it up in the color box. It has nothing to do with that code.